# Slick 2 - combine queries

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I would like to combine queries programatically to create a query resulting in all requirements satisfied. I can see there is a union and ++ operator, but I see no "intersection" or **.

Assuming [Slick FirstExample](https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/FirstExample.scala), let us have a code:

```
  val notCheap = coffees.filter(_.price>8.0)
  val notExpensive = coffees.filter(_.price<9.0)

  val midprice = coffees.filter(_.price>8.0).filter(_.price<9.0)

  println("Midprice coffees:")
  midprice foreach { case (name, supID, price, sales, total) =>
    println("  " + name + "\t" + supID + "\t" + price + "\t" + sales + "\t" + total)
  }
```

How can create `notCheap`, `notExpensive` and `midprice` so that `midprice` is created from `notCheap` and `notExpensive` to avoid code repetition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
implicit class CoffeesExtensions(q: Query[Coffees, Coffee]){
  def notCheap = q.filter(_.price > 8.0)
  def notExpensive = q.filter(_.price < 8.0)
  def midprice = q.notCheap.notExpensive
}

coffees.midPrice
```

There is also info about this in our Scala Days 2013 talk and the [Slick patterns talk at Scala eXchange 2013](http://slick.typesafe.com/talks/2013-12-03_Scala-eXchange/2013-12-03_Patterns-for-Slick-database-applications-Scala-eXchange.pdf). http://slick.typesafe.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks, look nice. The link http://slick.typesafe.com/docs/ does not seem to be very specific, though. I suggest either removing it, or replacing it with a link to some page describing this technique.